# How to Update Session in Next-Auth with NextJS app router?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am currently working on a Next.js 14 application where I'm using the next-auth library for user authentication. My application includes a custom API client, and I need to implement a feature to refresh the JWT token for the user when API call fails on Unauthorized error.

While I can successfully invoke the "refresh token" route handler and generate a new token, I'm seeking advice on **how to update the next-auth session on the server side**.

Any guidance, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Doesn't the refresh token route handles the session refresh for you? Are you using a custom route or one provided by next-auth?

Comment: @grekier I am using a custom one. I can't find the correct part of documentation for this. What is the route provided by next-auth to refresh session?